# Hiding schema browsers from inactive connection

Tags: oracle, toad

In toad when I use two new connections, and in every of them I have opened few schema browsers and editors, is it possible when I'm on one connection to hide all these schema browsers and editors from unused connection.

[image]

For example: when I'm on black connection I want to see just black editor and schema browser.

Comment: This seems like a question you really should be asking [on the TOAD forum](https://community.toadworld.com/p/forums).

Comment: I think that forum is dead as white walker :)

Comment: That may be so, but it's not really a programming question, is it?

Comment: No its not , but i thought that there could be toad users here.

Answer (score 0):

View - Options - Toolbars/Menu - Toolbars - Show only buttons for current connection on Windows bar

Answer (score 0):

I use the "**Show windows by connection**" button in TOADs toolbar. It is placed in the same toolbar where "Editor, Schema Browser, Session Browser, ... Commit, Rollback" buttons are.

If you click the "triangle" (list of values) icon next to the button, it'll show a list of all current connections. Click the one you're working with, and all other windows will automatically be minimized.